# use FB like button to share mp3

Tags: facebook-like, id3

I'm trying to share MP3s on facebook from my website using the FB like social plugin. I allow users to upload their own created mp3s. When the upload is complete I add ID3 tags (both V1 and V2.3) for song and artist name and an optional image field.
However, when one of the mp3s is shared on facebook, the song name and artist name are always blank (Unknown Title, Unknown Artist).
Does anyone know what facebook uses to extract mp3 info?
Thanks in advance for any help,
-A

Answer (score 2):

I see similar problems. For the 3 fields the FB MP3 player cycles through I get the name of the artist, "Unknown Album", and "Unknown Artist". I have the Title, Artist, Composer, Album and Album Artist fields filled in. I use `MP3tag.de 2.48`, `ID3V1` and `IDV2.3` `ISO-8859-1`.

Quora suggests FB tries to parse the file name: 
http://www.quora.com/Does-Facebook-support-ID3-audio-tagging
That would fit my data: my filenames are `YYYYMMDD_Surname_FirstName.mp3`, so it looks like FB is picking up the name as "Surname FirstName" and guessing it is the title.

When sharing an MP3 link manually, FB lets you change the artist and album:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5958345_upload-mp3-facebook.html
In an automated process, I guess you need to figure out the parsing convention for the filename.